# Remove Text Horizontal Padding in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, padding

There is extra horizontal padding for text in SwiftUI. This extra padding appears in some devices (canvas, simulator, and physical device) like **iPhone 14 Pro**, while it does not exist in other devices like **iPhone 14 Pro Max** (xCode Version 14.2). I'd like to have the **text** and **H1** aligned leading. How can I remove the extra padding?

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("H1")
                    .font(.custom("GillSans-bold", size: 18))
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "doc")
            }
            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.")
                .font(.custom("GillSans", size: 18))
                .background(.cyan)
            
        }
        .background(.yellow)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a padding. The box of your text is aligned to the center by default and text can't be of exact with of the screen. So you probably want to do something like:

```
VStack (alignment: .leading) {
...
}
```

Also you could do the same trick that you did in the first line by adding `Spacer` in `HStack` which will push the text to the edge.